# Pandas getting values from Pivot table

Tags: pandas

I am trying to sort by the 'acct' and group by the 'month'.

dataframe is this:

```
    acct       month   value

14    84  2014-09-30  393641
15    84  2014-10-31  393283
16    84  2014-11-30  383293
....
35    85  2014-10-31  291629
36    85  2014-11-30  289544
```

I do a pivot table

```
df2 = df.pivot_table ( index = ['month'], columns = "acct" )
```

This is the results:

```
                value     
acct              84       85
month                    
2014-09-30  393641.0       0.0
2014-10-31  393283.0  291629.0
2014-11-30  383293.0  289544.0
```

What is the best way to get values from the pivot?
I need to loop trough the 'value' to extract the data created for each account.

Thanks.

This is what worked for me to extract the data:

```
var = [ ]
for column in df2.columns.values:
    var.append ( df2 [ column ].tolist () )
```

Comment: You can use `df2 = df.pivot_table ( index = 'month', columns = "acct", values='value')` for remove `MultiIndex` from column.

Comment: that makes is a simpler df, but how would I loop through it to just get the values.  When I loop through it I get both the month and the values?  thanks so much.

Comment: this is what I am getting. month
2013-07-31    208372.0
2013-08-31    210669.0
2013-09-30    230171.0

Comment: Not sure if understand, what need? Select column? `df[85]` or `df['85']`? Or select column with index like `df.loc['2014-09-30',85]` ?

Comment: looking for all the values from the df[85] and df[85]

Comment: Yes, so `df[85]` does not work?

Comment: yes, but it gives me both the month and the value. Plus how would I know it was the '85' in a loop? thanks for much for your help.